# How to compile typescript at install time using afterinstall package.json?

Tags: typescript, npm-install, npm-scripts

I am trying to compile my `tsc` project just after installing it as a dependency.

I have an `tsconfig.json` file and locally (in the project) I can run tsc and it works.

I have declared this on my package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "postinstall": "npm run build",
    "build": "npx tsc -p ./tsconfig.json"
  },
```

after installing the package (currently from a private GitHub repo) the command fail because `.tsconfig.json` can not be found.

If I remove `-p ./tsconfig.json` and the parent project has typescript ALL of the parent project is compiled.

Can this be done? Or do I need to include the dist folder on my repository? (option that I do not like to be honest)